# Could someone please tell me what each of these components are?

Tags: power, schematics

I'm hoping someone could please identify the components in the picture below. The input is 32A, 3P from a variable frequency drive. The bottom most symbol has been identified as pumps/fans/HVAC/etc, I'm just unfamiliar with this generalised symbol that encompasses all of those.

EDIT: Added additional image with some text that may give context

Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would **CP** be the circuit panel and the little box with a handle on the right be a master shut-off?

Comment: The circle with the triangle is most likely 3-phase delta power.

Comment: Well, new picture now. And lots more info. :)

Comment: @jonk Hopefully that provides some more context, thanks for helping

Comment: Where is the VFD feeding? Into the top of the photo above the circle-triangle? Or do you mean it's just feeding the pump from the control panel?

Answer (score 0):

The components have been identified.

[image]

'WP' may stand for Water Pump. The hydraulic system may be water-based not oil-based.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I think the WP may stand for weatherproof/waterproof for the isolation switch, but could go either way.

Comment: Anytime, Nomicide! 32A, 3P, U/F, WP is with respect to the 25 kW pump motor.